# Understanding SOAP vs REST in more precise way

Tags: rest, web-services, soap

I have read a lot of articles on **SOAP vs REST** but still haven't got any satisfactory answer. I find both of them more or less the same. Basically here are my points of argument:

1. SOAP is the protocol while REST is an architectural pattern, but how? REST also defines a set of rules to follow (though not all are mandatory), and set of rules means protocol itself. Whereas SOAP provides a set of rules which must be followed (mandatory). So basically both are protocols, but with different levels of mandates. SOAP and REST both use HTTP protocol (in general) to transmit the data on the wire.
2. SOAP is sometimes called RPC because it calls the remote server's method when a client makes any request. But same is the case in REST also (indirectly Controller's method gets invoked on any REST request). So how SOAP is called RPC and REST not?
3. Many articles say that to change any parameter in a SOAP request, all the clients need to change their code. But the same is the case with REST also. If you change any parameter or its name in the request body of REST API, it must be changed at the client side also. Though it might not throw any error while calling the REST API if this change is not applied on the client-side, it will break the functionality for sure if that parameter is mandatory. So how in this case SOAP and REST are different?
4. SOAP needs WSDL to define its request and response bodies and the WS URL. But so is the case of REST. You need the REST API endpoint, its request body structure and response body structure to consume that particular REST API. It's just that there is no standard way to communicate this information in REST but SOAP has a standard way to publish this information in the form of WSDL (so basically WSDL is Swagger like implementation for SOAP?).
5. Here is the link to produce SOAP WS in Spring boot (I am from the Java side so) - https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/. It includes steps that depict that we need to first create an endpoint controller method, and that is mapped by some context information there in the request XML (by some kind of dispatcher servlet). But isn't this same thing happens in the case of REST API also. The dispatcher servlet picks the right class and method to execute based on the API (context path) received. Its just that this context is present in the request body in the case of SOAP, but in the request URI in the case of REST.
6. Here is the link to consume SOAP WS in Spring boot - https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/. It includes steps to call the SOAP request, which includes providing the WS URL, marshalling the request body, sending it, receiving the response, unmarshalling it again to the response object. But aren't these same steps followed in the case of REST API also? It's just that marshalling and unmarshalling is called serialization and deserialization in REST?

So from the above points in my mind, I find that REST is just a simplified and more flexible version of SOAP, that's it. If I have misunderstood anything, then please enlighten me because I really want to understand these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

> Understanding SOAP vs REST in more precise way

If you want to understand SOAP vs REST in a more precise way, you are probably going to need to understand REST and HTTP in a more precise way.

REST is an instance of an [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5) - which is to say it is a collection of architectural constraints.  You adopt those constraints because you want your architecture to have the [properties](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_4) that are induced from those constraints.

The [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) [encompasses](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2) the fundamental constraints upon components, connectors, and data that define the basis of the Web architecture, and thus the essence of its behavior as a network-based application.

(Mostly - Fielding's thesis also documents mismatches between the web and what you would expect from REST; for instance [Cookies](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4_2)).

HTTP is an application protocol "whose application domain is the transfer of documents over a network" ([Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s)).  It gives us a bunch of standardized meanings that are useful when moving documents around; including standardized request semantics (GET vs POST vs PUT...), authorization semantics, caching semantics, conditional requests, and so on.

The standardized semantics of messages where SOAP has trouble keeping up.  Caching responses, re-using those responses to service other requests, invaliding cached responses are standardized in HTTP, which means that we can put a *general purpose* cache in place, and it can perform useful work *even though the cache doesn't understand any of the documents*.

On the web, this worked *great* - because the work of interpreting the documents, and understanding how to manipulate the documents to advance the *business protocol*, was performed by humans.  You can, after all, create documents that describe the protocol to humans, and give them hints, so that they can actually do interesting things like publish technical questions to a website or fill a shopping cart with books to buy.

Now, you can give a human being a openapi/swagger document, or a WSDL, and they may be able to figure it out, but it's probably a lot easier to just use plainly written prose in a language appropriate for the human's locale.

But if the goal is to have *machines* manipulate the documents to advance the business protocol.... well, now we need more stuff.  HTTP gives you lots of documents over a network tools, so you don't need to recreate that from scratch, but it doesn't give you tools to help the machines understand documents.  Having a browser is great, you can follow links, fill out and submit forms... but the machine client needs to understand *which* links to follow in the browser, and what information to copy into the form.

(Notice that, for some common cases - like authentication forms or billing addresses - we have documented conventions that give us a sort of machine assist.  "Everybody" knows that this specific input control should be filled with a street address because the form metadata expresses that meaning in a commonly understood way).

Comment: I know what REST is and been using for years. My question to understand how it is different from SOAP. So basically you mean to say that REST is just simplified and flexible (and with more features like caching) version of SOAP, right?

Comment: You read my points, I want clarifications about those. Are they correct or I have misunderstood something?